# How to set GRUB default, not Windows Boot Manager

Tags: 12.04, grub2, uefi

I am using VAIO T series with Win 8 preinstalled, I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 on a different partition and set GRUB at default. But whenever I choose to boot Win 8, the next time I start the laptop, it Windows Boot Manager which shows up at default. How can I set GRUB default constantly?