# Use Windows Boot Loader to dual boot Ubuntu-MATE and Windows 10 (both UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

My laptop already installed Windows 10 UEFI and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu-MATE but I want to add Ubuntu Boot Entry into Windows. It should show something like:

[image]

I refer to some tutorial but they do not have UEFI and use EasyBCD (EasyBCD does't support UEFI Boot).

Comment: It is not posiible to add ubuntu boot entry into windows as windows boot manager cannot read linux file systems. However it is possible to add windows boot entry into ubuntu as ubuntu boot manager can read ntfs file systems and thus determine the presence of windows.

Comment: @rancho : but easyBCD can do that with non-UEFI system. Why not possible with UEFI system?

Comment: You can ask Windows to load grub as default. See [this question at AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349526/how-to-set-grub-default-not-windows-boot-manager).

Comment: Use rEFInd instead of easyBCD. rEFInd is the the ultimate bootloader anywhere! easyBCD does not support UEFI (yet). You can't add any other type of OS to Windows' bootloader because Win only supports other Win (like a mob thing or something).

Answer (score 0):

as @rancho pointed out it is not possible to add Ubuntu boot entry into the windows boot manager.

However if you install Ubuntu as a dual boot with GRUB it will give you the choice that you are looking for albeit in a text format rather than a graphical one.